# Главная страница для пользователей с разными ролями

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

Сайт с обучающими курсами. Пользователь заходит на главную страницу, где отображается список всех курсов. Пока пользователь не авторизован, он может только посмотреть список курсов или почитать о курсе подробнее. Авторизовавшись под одной из ролей (Админ, Преподаатель, Студент), он видит дополнительный функционал. Например Админ может добавлять или изменять записи, студент - записаться на курс (после чего запись меняется на "Записан на курс") или отписаться, преподаватель просто видит список курсов. Вопрос, как лучше поступить? Создать для каждой из ролей свою страницу с функционалом либо же написать одну страницу и скрывать функционал в зависимости от роли пользователя, например с помощью тега jstl "choose"?

Можно использовать: jsp, js + библиотеки и фреймворки.

Answer (score 1):

Если кратно, то можно использовать механизм сессий. При рендере проверять, кто запрашивает(авторизован/нет, какая роль, и так далее)